# What is a good site to download historical stock 'events' such as earnings releases?

Tags: data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What data sources are available online?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online)
>   [Earnings and valuation data sources online](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1207/earnings-and-valuation-data-sources-online)

I'd like to backtest some strategies involving earnings release surprises, as well as moves in correlated stocks.

Are there any sites that offer easy to 'scrape' tables/XML/JSON of all the past historical earnings, surprises etc dates?

The SEC.GOV site is a last resort as it's fairly convoluted to 'parse'.

Comment: "Where can I get (free) data online?" is the most over-asked question on here. Please please please look at the search results before posting this question yet again.